# System restarted after 15 mins of screen-sharing in Zoom

Tags: crash, gpu, restart, syslog

- Laptop: ASUS ROG Zephyrus G14
- OS: Ubuntu 21.04
- Kernel: 5.12.19
- Nvidia driver version: 460.91.03

`syslog` in time of restart:

```
Dec  7 17:12:01 cyber kernel: [30576.847272] usb usb4-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Dec  7 17:12:01 cyber kernel: [30576.847289] usb usb4-port2: config error
Dec  7 17:12:05 cyber kernel: [30580.956917] usb usb4-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Dec  7 17:12:05 cyber kernel: [30580.956978] usb usb4-port2: config error
Dec  7 17:12:09 cyber kernel: [30585.068878] usb usb4-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Dec  7 17:12:09 cyber kernel: [30585.068892] usb usb4-port2: config error
Dec  7 17:12:13 cyber kernel: [30589.156968] usb usb4-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Dec  7 17:12:13 cyber kernel: [30589.157037] usb usb4-port2: config error
Dec  7 17:12:17 cyber kernel: [30593.264895] usb usb4-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Dec  7 17:12:17 cyber kernel: [30593.264916] usb usb4-port2: config error
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
Dec  7 17:13:21 cyber kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.12.19-051219-gener
Dec  7 17:13:21 cyber kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Dec  7 17:13:21 cyber kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Dec  7 17:13:21 cyber kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
```

I'm curious what those symbols mean in `syslog` (`^@^@^@^@^`...). I was running Ubuntu in the Power saving mode (not utilizing Nvidia GPU). Can it be a problem with the AMD graphic card?

Upd. The same thing happened on the same laptop when using its second, more powerful GPU: Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060

Comment: Update UEFI before anything else. then make sure you're using known good USB peripherals and cables > It complained about some USB device. A problem with any other component, including the iGPU, is possible but extremely unlikely.